# DoubleTapToGo.js - Bind/Unbind based on browser size

Tags: javascript

We currently have https://github.com/zenopopovici/DoubleTapToGo installed in our site though it's disrupting traffic on desktop forcing all visitors to double click single click links in our navigation.

This is due to us needing the script to load for Mobile / Tablet viewers.

Does anyone know how to unbind the navigation on browser size and re-bind it on browser size?

Idea I tried but didn't seem to unbind:

```
<script async type="text/javascript">
var width,height;
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
width = this.innerWidth;
}

jQuery(window).resize(function($) { 

    if (width >= 600) {
        $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
        $( '#nav2 li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    } else {
        $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo('unbind');
        $( '#nav2 li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo('unbind');
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: wouldn't this overwrite the `$` variable in the resize event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overwriting the `$` with the event data. try this.

```
<script async type="text/javascript">
var width,height;
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
width = this.innerWidth;
}

jQuery(window).resize(function(event) { 

    if (width >= 600) {
        $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
        $( '#nav2 li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    } else {
        $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo('unbind');
        $( '#nav2 li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo('unbind');
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input dgeare, I'm not certain if it overwrites the $ variable but I believe my jquery isn't loading before it because its saying "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".